# Changing number to word in header for page number

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I change a number in word to text to reflect
in header as page number.  In other words change Page 2 to 
reflect as Page Two and consecutively page number the document correctly.

Comment: What version of Office are you using? 2003, 2007 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed this worked in Word 2007.

Insert your page number as usual into your document.  Then click in the page number field itself and turn on the field code (Shift-F9).  The field code should read something similar to:

```
{PAGE \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

Change MERGEFORMAT to CARDTEXT then exit field codes (F9).

Comment: IMO this is the simplest answer, and should work in most versions of Word. The only things I would point out (perhaps not relevant to the OP) are that (a) if the document is long (>100 pages), the text is "One hundred one" which is probably fine for U.S. English but isn't universal (others say "One hundred and one" or "A hundred and one" (But I doubt that text actually appears often in writing). And (b), if the OP wants to use a ToC, the page numbering will still follow the format defined in "Format Page Numbers" and AFAIK that cannot be set to the same format that Cardtext gives you.